# XCode File and Folder issue -

Tags: xcode

I like to have the 'normal' Model, ViewModel, View folder structure in XCode.

Like this:

[image]

However I want also have a structure like the image below besides the 'normal' structure.

I want to work with a structure that has the subject as folder name/structure, within there the Model, ViewModel, View e.t.c for that subject.

Like this:

[image]

Is there a way to create a ***kind of alias*** in the XCode structure that leaves the normal Structure in tact but accept the MVVMC my-structure setup? After trying many drag or copy or real system 'file aliases' *( of course they won't work, but just try it anyway)* methodes and searching the web I did not came to any solution. Any help-full tips?

Comment: So you want the very same code file to appear in two distinct places in the project navigator hierarchy?

Comment: Only showing, like I wrote an 'Kind of Alias'

Comment: Then the answer is No. Xcode has no provision for this.

Comment: I was afraid of this; no bash script or something like that? Who do I have to call as the in charge manager at Apple? ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Any help-full tips?

Yes: give up. Xcode has no provision for making very same code file to appear in two distinct places in the project navigator hierarchy. File an enhancement request if you think you have a persuasive use case.

Comment: I will do that, filling the request. Thank you.